# Rotate dual monitor screen 90 degrees on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg.conf

I am trying to rotate a dual monitor which is attached to the VGA output of my laptop. My system is Ubuntu 15.10.

However, here is the outcome I get when I use xrandr:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1-0 --rotate right
xrandr: output VGA-1-0 cannot use rotation "right" reflection "none"
```

I have seen other posts on this subject, which all recommend editing xorg.conf. I have tried that, too. Here's my current xorg.conf file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "layout"
Screen 0 "nvidia"
Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "intel"
Driver "modesetting"
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Option "AccelMethod" "None"
Option "RandRRotation" "True"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "intel"
Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "nvidia"
Driver "nvidia"
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
Option "RandRRotation" "True"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "nvidia"
Device "nvidia"
Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
Option "RandRRotation" "True"
EndSection
```

Still, I keep getting the same error when trying to use xrandr to rotate that screen.

Is there another way of doing so?

Comment: I find the easiest way to manage screen rotation/placement/resolution is by using the `arandr` GUI. You can then save the file in `arandr` and it will be some `xrandr` commands that you can look at or save such that it does so on login.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using arandr, too. When I right-click over the dual monitor screen, all options under "Orientation" are disabled, except for "normal", which is selected.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue!!

Comment: What is your GPU? What is the exact name of your dual monitor? Please, provide them to the end of your body.

Comment: Apparently this is because Canonical patched X so that the nvidia driver can't rotate the screen. https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999654/linux/randr-rotation-doesn-t-work/post/5108881/#5108881

Answer (score 1):

Timo Aaltonen has fixed this issue! Update your xorg-server. Thank you.

[image: xorg-server update]

Answer (score 0):

(EOL of 15.10 expires today! I hope this helps!)

There is an old app (2012) that did the trick for me in my previous laptop. It is called **Magick Rotation**. Fint the latest .deb file [here](https://launchpad.net/magick-rotation). Note, **apparently** it only works for Lenovo, Dell, Fujitsu, and HP. To install, do as usual:

```
sudo dpkg -i file.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The app has a nice GUI, that you can see below:

[image]

Note: since this is an old app, some old dependencies might be needed. **Be careful!**

In the Advanced Setup menu you can setup the onboard keyboard to run after rotation. It is very likely you will not have CellWriter (the default), as it is not shipped with 14.04 and newer ubuntus. In your case, this keyboard must be `onboard`. Change accordingly (see `onboard --help` for the full range of options).