# Rotating screen with Nvidia driver impossible. Why?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, xrandr, canonical, nvidia-prime

Using the proprietary NVIDIA driver (384.59), I can't rotate a screen. It works with the Intel drivers for the integrated graphics instead the Optimus/Prime. The control panel only offers the rotation "normal" and `xrandr` fails like this:

```
xrandr --output VGA-1-1 --rotate left
xrandr: output VGA-1-1 cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"
```

There are similar unanswered questions here: [Rotate dual monitor screen 90 degrees on Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793572/rotate-dual-monitor-screen-90-degrees-on-ubuntu-15-10) and [How can I rotate my notebook screen 90 degrees although 'xrandr --rotate' does not support it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802430/how-can-i-rotate-my-notebook-screen-90-degrees-although-xrandr-rotate-does-n)

`xorg.conf` has the "Device" section with `Option "RandRRotation" "true"` added as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115311/cannot-rotate-screen-with-xrandr), but no avail.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
    Option "RandRRotation" "true"
EndSection
```

Now the question: [It is claimed by a Nvidia dev](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/999654/linux/randr-rotation-doesn-t-work/) that Canonical patched X so that one can't rotate the screen using the proprietary driver. The linked issues are fixed by now though. Is this true and why?
Can I install an unpatched X or one that has this patch removed?

Comment: I asked a similar and also unanswered question earlier too... https://askubuntu.com/q/802430/367990

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate dual monitor screen 90 degrees on Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793572/rotate-dual-monitor-screen-90-degrees-on-ubuntu-15-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timo Aaltonen has fixed this issue! Thank you.

[image: xorg-server update]